# Looking for super computer technology suggestions

Tags: mpi, cuda, opencl

I'm writing some image processing software to detect bubbles in oil at work. One of the image filters I need (Perona Malik) seems like it will take a long time to compute. (It involves solving some partial differential equations numerically). One possible solution I'm thinking of investigating is using a super computer cluster. I've never had any experience with Beowulf clusters or the like ... Can anyone suggest some technologies I should consider. Any pros and cons of the different options would be useful to know as well.

Chris

Comment: You want suggestions on parallel PDE solvers?

Comment: Depends on the size of your problems. Nowadays, you can solve many problems on a GPU with OpenCL or CUDA. I don't know whether you can parallelize Perona Malik. It seems to be the case: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24299-gpu-perona-malik-anisotropic-diffusion

Comment: Hi sav, and welcome to scicomp!  I just want to clarify... Does the software that your using have allow you to run it in parallel?  Otherwise, a cluster would not improve your performance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, I am interested in Parallel PDE solvers. The paper that I read on perona-malik suggested parallel processing was applicable, although I still haven't sorted out all the details. Using a GPU is another option that I'm considering

Comment: How big are your images, and how many of them do you need to apply the filter to? Do you have access to a parallel computer at your company, or do you plan to buy a computer? You could pretty quickly implement and parallelize this with FEniCS and PETSc if you were so inclined.

Comment: The images are 1920x1080 pixels although the Perona-Malik Filter need only operate on a smaller area in that image. (Just the region with the oil, this can vary in size). We dont have a parrallel computer set up although we have a number of spare PC which could be used.

Comment: It seems like the area for the filter is the important part, how big is that? And how many images do you have to process?

Comment: It can vary. I'd say no larger than 800x1080, usually smaller. Each video is about 20 sec. We might do several hundred a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you invest in either a cluster or a supercomputer (I think they're different beasts, others may disagree) I suggest you invest in a beefy desktop workstation, maybe 2 x 4- or 6-core processors.  You can use this to try out all your parallelisation options -- MPI, OpenMP,  CUDA, OpenCL (these two will need a GPU), probably others.  Your experience on the workstation will provide useful input to your decision on further hardware purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I want to go down the GPU route I have a number of options:

**Shader languages**

- HLSL

  - use with xna
- GLSL

  - use with OpenTk
- Cg

  - use with Unity

I'm thinking of using OpenTk because it lets me use the GPU and integrates with monodevelop and visual studio which I use at work for other projects. It also alows me to use OpenCL if I should need it.

Comment: Why would you want to use shader languages? CUDA, OpenCL, AMP, Numba Pro, Arrayfire, etc, etc seem like better choices? Sure you could do it with shaders, but it's not what they were made for and it's more cumbersome to boot (in my opinion)